# Reading binary rainfall data (*.trm) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, precipitation, binary, trmm

I have some *.trm binary data that is merged [Tropical Rainfall Measuring Mission (TRMM)](http://trmm.gsfc.nasa.gov/) rainfall data.

I have to read it through ArcGIS for Desktop to extract rainfall data from this.

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS cannot work with TRMM data, however you can [download the TRMM data](http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/mirador/presentNavigation.pl?tree=project&project=TRMM&dataGroup=Gridded) in the [NetCDF](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004600000001000000) format which is supported by ArcGIS.

From Esri Help:

> NetCDF (network Common Data Form) is a file format for storing
>   multidimensional scientific data (variables) such as temperature,
>   humidity, pressure, wind speed, and direction. Each of these variables
>   can be displayed through a dimension (such as time) in ArcGIS by
>   making a layer or table view from the netCDF file.

Step-by-step instructions on how to download TRMM data, convert to NetCDF and visualize in ArcMap are here:

[Import a TRMM monthly  precipitation data file into ArcGIS](http://disc.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/dataholdings/?q=recipes/How-to-Import-Gridded-Data-in-NetCDF-Format-into-ArcGIS)

Comment: Sir, My data is in binary format which is .trm. It is not TRMM net cdf data. My question is to read that binary data in Arc GIS.

Comment: You cannot read .trm binary data in ArcGIS. Your only option is to go to their website and find the respective data in netcdf format. I am not aware of any piece of software for .trm binary data conversion into some other format.

Comment: But there is option in GIS to read Binary data or ASCII format. My question is we can't read binary data in Arc GIS. There would be procedure of reading binary data in Arc GIS

Answer (score -1):

Just explore GRADS an open source software which helps to convert the binary rainfall data to ascii format so as to read it in ArcMap. But you should know some bascis of C language to compile a small program to convert binary to ascii.